# Find the canonical form of a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I have a quadratic form:
$x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2} + 3x_{3}^{2} + 4x_{1}x_{2} + 2x_{1}x_{3} + 2x_{2}x_{3}$

How could I find canonical form of that? Trying to use Lagrange method, I came to this:

$(x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3})^{2} - 2x_{1}x_{2} + 2(\sqrt{3} - 1)x_{1}x_{3} + 2(\sqrt{3} - 1)x_{2}x_{3}$

But as you see, replacements here do not work.

This exercise is from task book, so I know the answer, but not a solution, it’s $y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2} - y_{3}^{2}$

Comment: Your first step is wrong; when you complete the $x_1$ square you must account for all the $x_1^2, x_1 x_2, x_1 x_3$ terms. So you need to pull out $(x_1 +2 x_2 +x_3)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing what canonical form might mean...

$$  (x+2y+z)^2 - 3 (y + \frac{z}{3})^2 + \frac{7}{3} z^2 $$
If it is required to have only $\pm 1$ as coefficients,
$$  (x+2y+z)^2 -  \left(y \sqrt 3 + \frac{z}{\sqrt3}\right)^2 + \left( \frac{\sqrt 7}{\sqrt3} z\right)^2 $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

how to do it

Algorithm discussed at [reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 &  - 3 &  - 1 \\ 
1 &  - 1 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 3 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: Yeah it is required to have only ±1 as coefficients

Comment: And what kind of replacements have you done?

Comment: I added some details in the question